# "Community" (the moderator) deleted a question that I linked as base question on an other post!

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, close-reasons, deleted-questions

If [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7765/do-i-realy-have-to-install-nvidias-driver-and-how-ubuntu-optimus?noredirect=1#comment12700_7765) question is deleted, the base of my [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436488/install-nvidia-driver-for-cuda-to-use-gpu-option-in-blender-ubuntu-13-10) will disappear!

What should I do?

Furthermore, it is NOT an already asked question, because it talks about OPTIMUS on Linux, case in which many users of Blender could be. And an answer is given in the other post. So I think that the post is useful.

That's it ;)

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fate of the original question aside… the best way to handle this is edit the original question to add (back) enough of the original context so your question can stand on its own. That sort of inter-post dependency works better in a threaded discussion forum, but as the content of this site is always expected to be updated and changed, it is best if each question/answer thread is able to stand on its own.

Comment: What should I do? I can't copy paste the whole post in the other (way too long and makes post n°2 unreadable) and I can't change anything because its closed! thanks for your help :)

Comment: @tuxtoriel I wouldn't copy the original post verbatim, but you could edit your new question in a way to read as if the original question was never asked. It just has to make sense to anybody who didn't see (or cannot view) the original question.

Comment: ok! Thanks, I'll do it! :)